# Avoid duplicate Patient on resource create

Tags: hl7-fhir, fhir-server-for-azure

When sending this request multiple times, I get multiple Patients created.

```json
{
  "resourceType": "Patient",
  "identifier": [
    {
      "use": "usual",
      "system": "urn:oid:2.16.840.1.113883.19.5",
      "value": "12345"
    }
  ],
  "active": true,
  "name": [
    {
      "family": "Levin",
      "given": [
        "Omri"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "gender": "male",
  "birthDate": "1980-09-24"
}
```

My assumption is that when I provide the `identifier`, it would reject the 2nd call, as that PAtient already exists. But seems that is not the case? How do I avoid these duplications?

(Tried it both on Azure and on Google cloud - both with the same result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to dig deeper into the docs. And the answer is here - https://www.hl7.org/fhir/http.html#ccreate

In my case adding the header `If-None-Exist: identifier=urn:oid:2.16.840.1.113883.19.5|12345` did the trick on Azure. On Google cloud, however, if trying to use V1 of the API we get an error for adding that header:

```json
{
    "issue": [
        {
            "code": "value",
            "details": {
                "text": "invalid_query"
            },
            "diagnostics": "conditional operations are not supported in API version v1",
            "severity": "error"
        }
    ],
    "resourceType": "OperationOutcome"
}
```

To overcome that we need to use `v1beta1`. So URL should change

```
- https://healthcare.googleapis.com/v1/projects/...
+ https://healthcare.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/...
```

Read more about the "v1" and "new v1beta1" difference [here](https://cloud.google.com/healthcare-api/docs/how-tos/transition-guide#new_v1beta1_v1)

Comment: Note that the beta implementation of conditional operations on GCP is currently not atomic, so if you create duplicate patients in quick succession some duplicates can get through. We are working to improve this functionality before promoting it to v1.

Comment: You can also always do a PUT. A FHIR PUT resource is a conditional PUT. Meaning if the data does not already exist it will create a new data. If it exist already then it will update the existing one. In this case you need to pass the url like -- ```url/identifier=someidentifier``` but as per FHIR standards the server functionality is implemented only in the HAPI FHIR server. So first try it in https://hapi.fhir.org/

Answer (score 1):

Altarnatively you could use conditional update/create (PUT with search/match criteria) instead of a POST i.e. `PUT Patient?identifier=urn:oid:2.16.840.1.113883.19.5|12345` with the same payload you have in your question.

Or you can POST a Bundle of one or more resources, also using PUT with search criteria :

```html
    {
  "resourceType": "Bundle",
  "id": "bundle-transaction",
  "meta": {
    "lastUpdated": "2014-08-18T01:43:30Z"
  },
  "type": "transaction",
  "entry": [
    {
      "fullUrl": "urn:uuid:61ebe359-bfdc-4613-8bf2-c5e300945f0a",
      "resource": {
      "resourceType": "Patient",
      "identifier": [
        {
          "use": "usual",
          "system": "urn:oid:2.16.840.1.113883.19.5",
          "value": "12345"
        }
      ],
      "active": true,
      "name": [
        {
          "family": "Levin",
          "given": [
        "Omri"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "gender": "male",
  "birthDate": "1980-09-24"
      },
      "request": {
        "method": "PUT",
        "url": "Patient?identifier=urn:oid:2.16.840.1.113883.19.5|12345"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

When using a Bundle, If no Patient resource with the same identifier already exists then the OperatioOutcome will return a `201 Created` otherwise you will get a `200 OK` and the resource will be updated, creating a new version of it.

You can read more about bundles here https://www.hl7.org/fhir/bundle.html